# jQuery - select on change event causes select-box to instantly close again in IE10 and FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, internet-explorer-10

i am having a very strange and annoying problem with binding jquery "on change" events to `<select>` - boxes in IE10 and (various) firefox-version.
this problem does not occur in Chrome or IE11.

the dropdown-menu which is opening after clicking a select-box is instantly closed again, but only if there is an "on change" event bound to it.
i am using quite a standard jquery routine here:

```
$(document).on("change", "#kp_gebdat_y, #kp_gebdat_m, #kp_gebdat_d", function () {

    var year = $("#kp_gebdat_y").val();
    var month = $("#kp_gebdat_m").val();
    var day = $("#kp_gebdat_d").val();

    $("#kp_gebdat").val(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
});
```

I already tried to mess around with `preventDefault()` but that doesn't change anyhting. it seems like the first dropdown is "focused" after any of the dropboxes are clicked in IE10.

here is a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem in IE10 and FF as well:
http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/7zyw2nff/1/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is not the JavaScript  - it is the markup itself. Do not nest the selectfields inside the label element.  Use one label for each select or do not nest the fields at all: http://jsfiddle.net/7zyw2nff/2/

Comment: @axel.michel oh yes, that's it! any idea why selects within labels behave like this in some versions of IE and FF? and - if you don't mind, please post this as an answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, the problem is not jQuery or the JavaScript event handler, it is the markup itself. The select fields are nested inside a label tag:

```
<label>
    <select type="text">
        <option value="0">Tag</option>
        [...]   
    </select>
    <select type="text">
        <option value="0">Monat</option>
        [...]   
    </select>
    <select type="text">
        <option value="0">Jahr</option>
        [...]   
    </select>   
</label>
```

And this is what causes the error: In case you focus the second or third select field, the event is delegated to the label, which is (in FF) bind to the first form field child - your first select field and focussing it - and that focus causes the immediate blur of second + third select field inside the same label. So you can either remove the label completely or nest each select in an own label:

```
<label>
    <select type="text">
        <option value="0">Tag</option>
        [...]   
    </select>
</label>
<label>
   [...]
</label>
```

I think at the end FF behaviour is correct, because an label should be related to one element.